# Is it possible to access a c++ template template constant parameter?

Tags: c++, class, templates, constants

I want to do something like this:

```
template<template<int d, class>
         class container,
         int dim = d, typename content_data_type>
class MyClass {
};
```

My Compiler tells me that this is not possible because "d" is not defined outside of:

```
template<int d, class> class container
```

Is there maybe another way of doing this ?

Thanks in advance for any help on this topic.

**UPDATE:**

@ Rook: i want to access the "dim" and "content_data_type" parameters later on in a specialization

e.g.

General class:

```
template<template<int d, class>
         class container>
class MyClass {
};
```

Spec. class:

```
template<>
class MyClass<vec> {
    vec c; // Error: vec needs template parameters
};
```

This gave me an error because i used my template class "vec" whitout template parameters, i expected the compiler to deduce the template parameters, e.g. when i use

```
MyClass<vec<3, float> >
```

then variable "c" should have the type

```
vec<3, float>
```

Because this didn't work, I thought i can create two excplicit template paramters "dim" and "content_data_type" which i can access in the specialization class like this:

```
template<template<int d, class t>
     class container,
     int dim = d, typename content_data_type = t>
class MyClass<vec> {
    vec<dim, content_data_type> c;
};
```

... and sorry again for not being specific enough with the initial question :)

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Evidently you're going about it the wrong way, but it is hard to give you useful advice without knowing a little more about the underlying problem.

Comment: do you have a complete compilable program?

Comment: @SteveJessop maybe post that as an answer anyway.. the answer to the OP's question in the title is obviously 'NO' for the reason you state

Comment: @stijn: done. Thanks, I didn't notice that my comment implied a concrete answer to the question asked :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you're doing makes sense, so the answer is "no".

The template parameter `container` is a *class template*, not a class. When `MyClass` is instantiated, its argument is the whole template, not just one instantiation of it. So it's not possible to default the dimension of `MyClass` to "the dimension of `container`", because `container` doesn't have values for its own template parameters. Your class `MyClass` can create and use one or more instantiations of `container` with different values of `d`, but it isn't given any one of them in particular, it's given the template.

By analogy, suppose you pass a pointer-to-function `f` as a parameter to a function `g`. You can't then use "the arguments passed to `f`" in the definition of `g`. The function `g` can call `f` one or more times with different arguments, but it isn't given any one call in particular, it's given the function.

From your update:

> e.g. when i use `MyClass<vec<3, float> >`

You don't use `MyClass<vec<3, float> >`, there's no such thing. As I say, `MyClass` takes a *template* not a *class*. `vec` is a template, `vec<3, float>` is a class. It sounds like maybe you don't need a template as a template parameter at all.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I use the solution proposed by stijn , but your answer points out my error in reasoning. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

normally the container would expose the dim member, so this would work:

```
template< template< int, class> class container, int dim, class content_data_type >
class MyClass 
{
public:
  typedef typename container< dim, content_data_type > container_type;

  static const int dim = container_type::dim;
};

template< int d, class >
class acontainer
{
public:
  static const int dim = d;
};

MyClass< acontainer, 2, sometype > x;
std::cout << "container size " << x.dim << std::endl;
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was trying to avoid, i do not want to specify the dimension and type two times e.g. MyClass<vec<2, float>, 2, float>

Comment: that's not needed at all (nor legal in your exampl). The syntax I propose is `MyClass< vec, 2, float > x;`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a workaround, you have to define the two arguments as a *type* and a *static* exposed by the container class though (see for example `boost::array`)

```
#include <iostream>

template <int d, class T>
struct container
{
  typedef T value_type;
  static const int static_size = d;
};

template<typename cont, int d = cont::static_size, class T = typename cont::value_type>
struct A
{
  static const int dimension = d;
};

int main(void)
{
  A<container<10, int> > a;
  std::cout << a.dimension << std::endl;
}
```